# WP Ecommerce, Gold Cart and pagination

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

This one is driving me mad! Pagination does not work in that it was displaying the same set of products on every page - now after resaving permalinks (twice as recommended) clicking on page 2 results in the message "There are no products in this group."

I have done everything advised - resaving permalinks, activating and deactivating WPEC,  disabling WP Total Cache etc - nothing works (can't find a lot of help out there including on the WPEC forum)

My next shop will be built using a different plugin!)

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kludge, not a fix. This patch fixes the problem, but doesn't identify why it is happening.

In file

```
wp-content\plugins\wp-e-commerce\wpsc-includes\theme.functions.php
```

locate the function

```
function wpsc_display_products_page( $query )
```

Add the following code just before the WP_QUERY object is created:

```
if(!empty($query['tag'])){
    $args['product_tag'] = $query['tag'];
}

// John Larysz. January 2012
//
// Patch to get over the problem that Wordpress is not paginating for this site.
//
     if ( isset($_GET['items_per_page']) && $_GET['items_per_page'] > 0 )
        {
        $args['showposts'] = $_GET['items_per_page'];
        }
     else
     {
     $args['showposts'] = get_option('wpsc_products_per_page');
     }
      if ( isset($_GET['paged']) && $_GET['paged'] > 0 )
         {
         $args['paged'] = $_GET['paged'];
         }
      if ( isset($_GET['product_order']) && strlen($_GET['product_order']) > 0 )
         {
         $args['order'] = $_GET['product_order'];
         }
      if ( isset($_GET['product_search']) && strlen($_GET['product_search']) > 0 )
         {
       $category_list = get_terms('wpsc_product_category','name__like=All Products');
         $args['s'] = $_GET['product_search'];
      $args['wpsc_product_category'] = 'All Products';
         $args['wpsc_product_category__in'] = $category_list[0]->term_taxonomy_id;
         }

// End of patch


$temp_wpsc_query = new WP_Query($args);

}
// swap the wpsc_query objects
list( $wp_query, $temp_wpsc_query ) = array( $temp_wpsc_query, $wp_query );
$GLOBALS['nzshpcrt_activateshpcrt'] = true;
```